# I need to filter the listview using recyclerView by date(between start date and end date) stored in Room Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am storing data in Amount in Roomdatabase with current date.The app successfully storing the data and showing me list stored item in recylerview with the current date.
Now i need o filter the  result sum of total amount i added by date like i want to show list with start date and end date. i can get the sum of above using query but can not populate the list between dates.

i hope i described the question so that you can understand. here is my Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView cash,card,tAmount,tDate;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RoomAdapter roomAdapter;
Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );



    btn =(Button)findViewById ( R.id.fbtn );

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById ( R.id.myrecView );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager (this  ) );

    cash=(TextView)findViewById ( R.id.cashTxt );
    card=(TextView)findViewById ( R.id.cardText );
    tAmount=(TextView)findViewById ( R.id.total_amount );





    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> materialDateBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
            materialDateBuilder.setTitleText ( "Select date Range" );
            final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker=materialDateBuilder.build();
            materialDatePicker.show ( getSupportFragmentManager (), "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER");

            materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener( new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener ()
            {

                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {

                            Pair selectedDates = (Pair) materialDatePicker.getSelection();

                            final Pair<Date, Date> rangeDate = new Pair<>(new Date((Long) selectedDates.first), new Date((Long) selectedDates.second));
                            Date startDate=rangeDate.first;
                            Date endDate=rangeDate.second;
                            //SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");

                            long sDates= startDate.getTime ();
                            long eDates=endDate.getTime ();



                            AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext (), AppDatabase.class, "myincome").allowMainThreadQueries ().build();
                            UserDao userDao = db.userDao();
                            userDao.newAllExpensesFromTo ( sDates,eDates );
                            String cIncome= String.valueOf ( userDao.newAllExpensesFromTo ( sDates,eDates ) );
                            tAmount.setText ( cIncome );

                          // ArrayList<Income> incomes= new ArrayList<> (userDao.newAllExpensesFromTo ( sDates,eDates ));


                            ArrayList incomes=new ArrayList (userDao.newAllExpensesFromTo ( sDates,eDates ));


                            roomAdapter= new RoomAdapter ( incomes );
                            recyclerView.setAdapter ( roomAdapter );

                            roomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();


                          //  Log.d ("SELECTED DATE :","Converted Dates"+  simpleFormat.format(sDates) + " Second : " + simpleFormat.format(eDates));

                            Log.d ("SELECTED DATE :","Converted Dates"+userDao.newAllExpensesFromTo ( sDates,eDates )+incomes.size () );

                        }
                    });





        }
    } );

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            getRoomData();
            getRoomDataSum();
            getCashSum();
            BottomSheet bottomSheet=new BottomSheet ();
            bottomSheet.show ( getSupportFragmentManager () ,bottomSheet.getTag () );
        }
    } );

    getRoomData();
    getRoomDataSum();
    getCashSum();

}
```

This is the query that returns the sum of amount i have added

```
    @Query("SELECT SUM (Amount) FROM myIncome WHERE Date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
int  newAllExpensesFromTo(Long startDate,Long endDate);
```

and this is adapter

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.myViewHolder>{

List<Income> incomes;
Context context ;
List<Integer> customList;

public RoomAdapter(List<Income> incomes) {
    this.incomes = incomes;

}


public RoomAdapter(ArrayList<Income> cincomes) {
    this.incomes = cincomes;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.fragment_blank ,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder ( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    
  Date date = incomes.get ( position ).getDate ();
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
  String stringDate = dateFormat.format ( date );
  
    holder.AmountType.setText ( incomes.get ( position ).getType ()  );
    holder.textViewAmount.setText ( String.valueOf (  incomes.get (  position).getAmount () ));
    holder.company.setText ( incomes.get ( position ).getCompany ());

    String cName= (String) holder.company.getText ();



    holder.dateText.setText (stringDate);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return incomes.size ();
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewAmount,AmountType,company,dateText;
    ImageView imageView;
    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );

        AmountType=itemView.findViewById ( R.id.AmountType );
        textViewAmount=itemView.findViewById ( R.id.txtViewAmount );
        company=itemView.findViewById ( R.id.Company );
        imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.img1 );
        dateText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.dateText);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

hi so finally i have found the solution. perhaps no one answer to my question.
the problem i found was in my query in the above query i was trying to get sum of the result but i wanted to populate the list also. but the above query will only show you the sum will not show you the list of the result.

so the right query is

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myIncome WHERE Date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
List<Income>  newAll(Long startDate,Long endDate);
```

this will bring the list and show the listView of items between your filter dates.thanks